# Is a copy made when function returns a data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I am updating a set of functions that previously only accepted `data.frame` objects to work with `data.table` arguments.

I decided to implement the function using R's method dispatch so that the old code using `data.frame`s will still work with the updated functions. In one of my functions, I take in a `data.frame` as input, modify it, and then return the modified `data.frame`. I created a `data.table` implementation as well. For example:

```
# The functions
foo <- function(d) {
  UseMethod("foo")
}

foo.data.frame <- function(d) {
  <Do Something>
  return(d)
}

foo.data.table <- function(d) {
  <Do Something>
  return(d)
}
```

I know that `data.table` works by making changes without copying, and I implemented `foo.data.table` while keeping that in mind. However, I return the `data.table` object at the end of the function because I want my old scripts to work with the new `data.table` objects. Will this make a copy of the `data.table`? How can I check? According to the documentation, one has to be very explicit to create a copy of a `data.table`, but I am not sure in this case.

The reason I want to return something when I do not have to with `data.tables`:

My old scripts look like this

```
someData <- read.table(...)
...
someData <- foo(someData)
```

I want the scripts to be able to run with `data.table`s by just changing the data ingest lines. In other words, I want the script to work by just changing `someData <- read.table(...)` to `someData <- fread(...)`.

Comment: Only `:=` and `set*` functions modify `data.table` by reference. So, if you're use `:=` or any of the `set*` functions within your function, you may need to work on `copy(d)` if you don't want `d` to be modified by reference. For ex: if you do: `ans <- d[, lapply(.SD, sum), by=cols]`, then there's nothing changed by reference here.

Comment: @Arun Sorry if my question was unclear. I do want `d` to be modified by reference, so I did make use of the `:=` and `set*` functions to modify the `data.table` in my `foo.data.table` function. If I modify `d` within the function by reference, then does `return(d)` return a copy of `d`?

Comment: no it doesn't.. you can use `tracemem` to check these things in general. Ex: `foo <- function(x) { x[, bar := 1L]; return(x) }; x = data.table(a=1:5, b=6:10); tracemem(x); foo(x)`. It'll result in some verbose after `foo(x)` if any copy was made. Alternatively you can use the `address()` function to test if the columns of `x` has the same address before and after the function.. and if so, no copy was made.

Comment: @Arun Thanks for the help, and for developing the package! It has only been recently that I had to worry about memory issues with R, which is why I started looking into `data.table`s. I did not know about the `tracemem` and `address` functions. Can you can make an answer so that I can accept and close this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Arun for his answer in the comments. I will be using his example in his comments to answer the question.

One can check if copies are being made by using the `tracemem` function to track an object in R. From the help file of the function, `?tracemem`, the description says:

> This function marks an object so that a message is printed whenever the internal code copies the object. It is a major cause of hard-to-predict memory use in R.

For example:

```
# Using a data.frame
df <- data.frame(x=1:5, y=6:10)
tracemem(df)
## [1] "<0x32618220>"
df$y[2L] <- 11L
## tracemem[0x32618220 -> 0x32661a98]: 
## tracemem[0x32661a98 -> 0x32661b08]: $<-.data.frame $<- 
## tracemem[0x32661b08 -> 0x32661268]: $<-.data.frame $<- 
df
##   x  y
## 1 1  6
## 2 2 11
## 3 3  8
## 4 4  9
## 5 5 10

# Using a data.table
dt <- data.table(x=1:5, y=6:10)
tracemem(dt)
## [1] "<0x5fdab40>"
set(dt, i=2L, j=2L, value=11L) # No memory output!
address(dt) # Verify the address in memory is the same
## [1] "0x5fdab40"
dt
##    x  y
## 1: 1  6
## 2: 2 11
## 3: 3  8
## 4: 4  9
## 5: 5 10
```

It appears that the `data.frame` object is copied twice when changing one element in the `data.frame`, while the `data.table` is modified in place without making copies!

From my question, I can just track the `data.table` or `data.frame` object, `d`, before passing it on to the function, `foo`, to check if any copies were made.

Comment: Excellent! You can also check for `address(dt$x)`.

Comment: might also want to check when the return value is stored, so someData = foo(someData)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure this adds anything, but as a cautionary tale note the following behavior:

```
library(data.table)
foo.data.table <- function(d) {
  d[,A:=4]
  d$B <- 1
  d[,C:=1]
  return(d)
}
set.seed(1)
dt     <- data.table(A=rnorm(5),B=runif(5),C=rnorm(5))
dt
#             A         B            C
# 1: -0.6264538 0.2059746 -0.005767173
# 2:  0.1836433 0.1765568  2.404653389
# 3: -0.8356286 0.6870228  0.763593461
# 4:  1.5952808 0.3841037 -0.799009249
# 5:  0.3295078 0.7698414 -1.147657009
result <- foo.data.table(dt)
dt
#    A         B            C
# 1: 4 0.2059746 -0.005767173
# 2: 4 0.1765568  2.404653389
# 3: 4 0.6870228  0.763593461
# 4: 4 0.3841037 -0.799009249
# 5: 4 0.7698414 -1.147657009
result
#    A B C
# 1: 4 1 1
# 2: 4 1 1
# 3: 4 1 1
# 4: 4 1 1
# 5: 4 1 1
```

So, evidently, `dt` is passed by reference to `foo.data.table(...)` and the first statement, `d[,A:=4]`, modifies it by reference, changing column `A` in `dt`.

The second statement, `d$B <- 1`, forces the creation of a copy of `d` (also named `d`) scoped internal to the function. Then rhe third statement, `d[,C:=1]`, modifies *that* by reference (but does not affect `dt`), and `return(d)` then returns the copy.

If you change the order of the second and third statements, the effect of the function call on `dt` is different.

Comment: The way I understood the question is, assuming that the function - up until the point of `return(.)` - did not result in a `copy`, does just the statement `return(.)` result still in a copy...

Comment: I think you raise an important point. The resulting code from my function is a little ambiguous, since I am coding with side-effects and do not require the `<-` operator because I am modifying the `d` in place (i.e. `foo(d)` is enough, but i used `d<-foo(d)`). I just had a special case of wanting to conform to my older code base. I was careful to use `data.table` functions for modifying values and creating columns in my function so that no copy is made up until the point of `return`. I was just unsure about the behavior of `return`ing an `data.table` object.